# Is there a way to modify a column value in a Pandas dataframe based on the column name?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas dataframe from imported Excel spreadsheet tab with multiple table formats on the same tab needs to be manipulated to transform value for adding a tag and include the value in parenthesis - e.g "Denver" can become "METRO(Denver)" in the CITY column.

I am able to import the spreadsheet tab using below but unable to find the solution to locate different columns and transform value.

```
import pandas as pd
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\Excel Work Request - Intake Form.xlsx")
table = xls_file.parse('Demographics Input')
```

Data format on excel is as below:

```
>1  Note to user
>2  Note line 2
>3  Line 3
>4  Line 4: Line4-value
>5  Account name xyz
>6
>.
>.
>.
>13 TABLE1
>14 Table1-header-row [14 column headers]
>15 Blank line
>16 n1 rows of Table1-values [14 column values ]
>   <variable blank rows/lines>
>   TABLE2
>   Table2-header-row [ 13 column headers ]
>   n2 rows of Table2-table-values [ 13 column values ]
>   <some blank rows/lines>
>   TABLE3
>   Table3-header-row [ 11 column headers ]
>   n3 rows of Table3-table-values [ 11 column values ]
>   <variable blank rows/lines>
>   TABLE4
>   Table4-header-row [ 6 column headers ]
>   n4 rows of Table4-table-values [ 6 column values ]
>   <variable blank rows/lines> 
>   < some information not used in processing >
```

The requirement is to be able to access values in columns from tables 1-4 which are in different formats (multiple table formats on same tab), identify the column for each type and apply some rule to transform. I was looking at df.loc but since I have not much experience with Pandas unable to identify a solution.